# Display dropdown based on checked box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a group of checkboxes 'box' now i want my dropdown list to show names based on the checkbox clicked by retrieving from database .

code:

```
$sql = "Select distinct empname from mstEmp where teamtype='$d' order by empname";
$objDB->SetQuery($sql);

$res = $objDB->GetQueryReference();

if(!$res)
    exit("Error in SQL : $sql");

if($objDB->GetNumRows($res) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        print("<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>");
    }
}

mysql_free_result($res);
```

Comment: where is your code buddy

Comment: please write some code and then after post the question...

Answer (score 0):

1.select.jsp

```
<%@page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showData(){ 
 if (document.form.check.checked==true){

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
var url="select2.jsp";
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}
}
function stateChanged(){ 
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
 document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;   

} 
}
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try{
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e){
 try  {
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }
 catch (e){
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 }
 return xmlHttp;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<br><br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="check"  onclick="showData();">

<div id='name'>
<b>Select Data</b>  
<select name='name' >
<option value='-1'></option>
</select>
</div> 
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```